# Webview in a dialog scrolls up and down continuously

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, android-dialogfragment

I implemented a little `android webview` into a `DialogFragment`. I set a little text programmatically with the method: `webView.loadData(myString, "text/html", "utf-8");`

**my xml layout:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@id/id_layout_list_dialog"
    style="@style/Window.Dialog"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    ...

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/id_webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

   ...

</LinearLayout>
```

**The problem**: the problem is the Dialog goes up and down continuously. If I don't call the `webView.loadData` method the problem disappears.
Moreover, the first time I call the Dialog, it is still. The second time it start goes up and down continuosly.

Why I get this issue? How I can solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I solved this issue simply change height from `match_parent` to `wrap_content`

```
<WebView
        android:id="@+id/id_webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```